# Is a 'God' ViewModel desired in WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm

My application has user controls within user controls. Please see a screen shot of one of the most beautiful applications of all time (UC = user control):

[image]

All the properties live in the MainWindow code behind, there are none in my UserControls. To bind to my properties I use

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1,AncestorType=Window}}"
```

This works fine but, it does mean all binding properties are in my MainWindow code behind (or the MainWindow ViewModel).

Is this desired in a MVVM (or should I say WPF) approach, in that all the children share the same ViewModel?

Answer (score 5):

I think its bad practice to have a God ViewModel, the topmost ViewModel, let's call it `MainWindowViewModel`, should only hold data and behavior coupled to that of the MainWindow, which usually is very thin, all other work should be delegated to submodels.

If you have a docking manager or other window manager logic that code should reside in the `MainWindowViewModel`.

Here is a example of a ViewModel I've made that delegates the behavior to sub models

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/blob/master/FreePIE.GUI/Shells/MainShellViewModel.cs

I do not think it's good practice to pass around data to sub models, it creates dependencies between models. It's better to use a Event aggregation pattern, this way all models interested in data change can subscribe to the event.

**Update**: I did an improvement to my Main window model, instead of the constructor taking all sub view models it now takes a collection of viewmodels. And then I configure the IoC to inject correct models

```
private void ConfigurePanels()
{
    kernel.Bind<PanelViewModel>().To<ConsoleViewModel>();
    kernel.Bind<PanelViewModel>().To<ErrorsViewModel>();
    kernel.Bind<PanelViewModel>().To<WatchesViewModel>();
}
```

This makes the main model a little less coupled to the sub models, before change

```
    public MainShellViewModel(ConsoleViewModel consoleViewModel,
                              ErrorsViewModel errorsViewModel,
                              WatchesViewModel watchesViewModel
        )
        : base(resultFactory)
    {            
        Tools = new BindableCollection<PanelViewModel> {consoleViewModel, errorsViewModel, watchesViewModel};
    }
```

and after

```
    public MainShellViewModel(IEnumerable<PanelViewModel> panels)
        : base(resultFactory)
    {
        Tools = new BindableCollection<PanelViewModel> (panels);
    }
```

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/commit/1102292d35a26d7693593266042cde9d9f3b4c89

Comment: Interesting and big thank you for the link. But if my MainWindow has many UserControls, which are supposed to bind via DependancyProperties, then doens't this mean my  MainWindowViewModel has to be a god view?

Comment: Yeah well, yes and no, it needs to hold the structure of the entire  Main window inclding children. But in reality with Dependency injection it only means it needs to hold its closest children. The children will load its own children using IoC.

Comment: By the way if you have many children directly under Main view then maybe you should start to think about separation of concerns

Comment: Got an up-vote so took the opportunity to improve my code

Answer (score 1):

Unless overwritten, child controls will inherit the DataContext (except for children of an ItemsControl).

If you aren't explicitly setting the DataContext on all your controls you should be fine (but your coupling is high... ie, your usercontrol now assumes it will only be used in one specific configuration)

If you are explicitly setting the DataContext, then this becomes a problem of Dependency Injection.  If a grand-grand-grandchild usercontrols requires data from the topmost viewmodel, then that data should probably be passed to the closest level viewmodel.  Think about it.  This data is a clearly a dependency of the ViewModel bound to the UserControl.